# cannot update pyplot dynamically in python 3.5

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow

Want to use the following piece of code to dynamically demonstrate how the prediction (<<2) is approaching the real values (<<1). However, only <<1 shows up and totally cannot see <<2 showing up. Any idea to fix it ?

```
.....
# plot the real data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data)     <<<< 1
plt.ion()
plt.show()

for i in range(1001):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs:x_data, ys:y_data})
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print(sess.run(loss,feed_dict={xs:x_data, ys:y_data}))
        try: 
             ax.lines.remove(lines[0])
        except Exception:  # if plotting the first time
             pass
        prediction_value = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={xs:x_data})
        lines = ax.plot(x_data,prediction_value,'r-', lw = 5)        <<< 2
        plt.pause(0.1)
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

`plt.show()` waits for you to close the plot windows before proceeding. If you remove it, but still keep the `plt.ion()` and your platform supports it, it should run fine:

```
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(0, 0, 'o')

for i in range(1,10):
    ax.plot(i, i, 'o')
    plt.pause(1)
```

works for me with matplotlib 2.0.0, Python 3.5 on Mac (draws a point every second)

Comment: I added a sample to my answer. See if this simple code works. If it does, check in your code if you ever reach <<<2.

Comment: I executed this piece of code: for 10 seconds there's nothing shown up; after 10 seconds, a fig of ten plots were shown at once. Can these ten points be shown one by one ?

Comment: Try adding `plt.draw()` before `plt.pause()`. According to [this](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#interactive-example), the method functions of an Axes instance do not call `draw_if_interactive()`. But if this is the case, it shouldn't work with me, yet it does...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `plt.show()` at the end of your script. Otherwise it blocks everything else, as the plotting window takes over the event loop.

In order to show the figure, use `plt.draw()` in interactive mode.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data)
plt.ion()
plt.draw()

for i in range(1001):
    ...
    lines = ax.plot(x_data,prediction_value,'r-', lw = 5)       
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You code can only show plot that's drawn last time. What I am intent to do is first draw the scatter points, and then draw the red line after 50 learning steps, and then after the another 50 learning steps, remove the original red line and re-draw a new red line ..... the red line constantly changing ...

Comment: This code shows how to update a plot and thus solves the problem of the additional plots not showing up. Of course I cannot give you a complete working code here, because I cannot run the code from the question. If you decide to provide a [mcve] in your question, a more detailed solution might be possible.

Comment: Showing up all lines onto the same figure is really not the intent. All I want to do is just having ONE line shown each time. Thus having an effect of one line changing its curve gradually.

Comment: Instead of the 3 dots (`...`) in the answer you may put everything which you need to let this happen, like the if statement or the removal of the previous line.

Comment: Sure. I am adding code that can be executed immediately above.

Answer (score 0):

Adding magic command of %matplotlib serves the intention, with a popped-up window drawn on. 
But just wondering whether this is the only way ... any other way without any additional window popped up ?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.